# Calculating points around a circle in sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I have adapted some code from a great article I found about circle drawing by Mukund Sivaraman to execute a passed function for each point on a given circle:

```
template<class Function>
static void For_each_point_on_circle(Image *image, int radius, Function function)
{
    int x, y;
    int l;
    l = (int) radius * cos (M_PI / 4);
    for (x = 0; x <= l; x++)
    {
        y = (int) sqrt ((double) (radius * radius) - (x * x));
        function(image, x, y);
        function(image, x, -y);
        function(image, -x, y);
        function(image, -x, -y);
        function(image, y, x);
        function(image, y, -x);
        function(image, -y, x);
        function(image, -y, -x);
  }
}
```

However, what I really need is to calculate the points around the circle in sequence, so the calls to function(image, x, y) will go from 0 to 360 degrees in sequence rather than skipping about, which is acceptable when drawing the circle.

I could calculate all the points and sort them, but I was hoping someone may know a way to do it properly, maybe using multiple loops each calculating a segment each?

Many thanks.

Comment: How far apart are the points on the circle? (1 degree?)

Comment: Just 1 pixel away from each other, not necessarily any fixed degrees away. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to go round the circle in even spaces (even with regard to arc length, not x-axis) I would suggest using polar coordinates and a suitable division of 2*PI based on how many points you want to plot.

Comment: What is wrong with the obvious `function(image, radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle))`?

Comment: @Danny: He doesn't have an angle (though there may be a way to figure one out)

Comment: @Danny: it is easier to stay in pixel coordinates then try to step in polar coordinates. the angular pixel spacing isn't constant around the circle. if you wanted to compute it, it would be a function of angle and resolution.

Comment: That would be a very elegant Danny, thanks. I would have to work out the angle first as I only have a radius.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, because this doesn't allow you to generate multiple adjacent pixels with the same x value but different y values, as you would expect near y = 0.

Comment: @mbeckish: it draws 1/8th of a circle and mirrors it 8 times.

Comment: @atb - Yes, but that doesn't have anything to do with drawing multiple values at the same x location.  For example, near the left and right sides of the circle, the arc should eventually be approximated by a vertical line (i.e. several y values at the same x value).  His algorithm cannot produce that.

Comment: @mbeckish: i believe his algorithm never steps far enough to get in that situation, it only walks 45 degrees from noon, the rest of the circle is mirrored. but you do point out a flaw in my proposed answer! thanks, i'll fix it...

Comment: @atb - Nevermind, I see how his solution gets around it.  Near x==0, a bunch of points are created with adjacent x values, but the same y value (due to rounding).  He then reuses those values, but swaps the x and y, to generate points with adjacent y values but the same x value.  So yes, your solution needs to do that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this should do it:

```
template<class Function>
static void For_each_point_on_circle(Image *image, int radius, Function function)
{
    int x, y;
    int l;
    l = (int) radius * cos (M_PI / 4);
    for (x = -l; x < l; x++)
    {
        y = (int) sqrt ((double) (radius * radius) - (x * x));
        function(image, x, y);
    }
    for (x = -l; x < l; x++)
    {
        y = (int) sqrt ((double) (radius * radius) - (x * x));
        function(image, y, -x);
    }
    for (x = -l; x < l; x++)
    {
        y = (int) sqrt ((double) (radius * radius) - (x * x));
        function(image, -x, -y);
    }
    for (x = -l; x < l; x++)
    {
        y = (int) sqrt ((double) (radius * radius) - (x * x));
        function(image, -y, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close, it produces this output: http://i.imgur.com/XIGWy.png. I shall work on it to fill in the holes, I should be ok now. I will update the main post with the full code when done. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: @user1454345 - This is what I was getting at in my comments above.  The bigger the radius, the more of an issue this will be.

Comment: @atb - Nevermind, I missed the cos (M_PI / 4) factor in your calculation of l.  While this helps to break it up into 4 loops, it doesn't really fix the issue.  As you increase the radius, eventually it will get big enough so that, within one quadrant, adjacent x values will map to y values that are not adjacent.  I think the only way around it is to calculate pixels for each x value and separately for each y value within the range.

Comment: It does appear to work for the radius values I've tried, http://imgur.com/aRyC8. - The gradient shows the order the pixels are drawn.

Comment: @atb - You are correct, it works up to the point where radius * radius gets too big.

Comment: @mbeckish - should work as long as `radius * radius <= INT_MAX`

Comment: FYI: After further testing I've found the final loop should be from +l to -l, e.g.: for (x = l; x >= -l; x--) - Otherwise the pixel positions in the final segment are calculated in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article on pathing out a circle in discrete steps. Its motivation is for a CNC machine stepper motor controller, but maybe it will work for your purposes.

https://github.com/Falmarri/cnc/blob/master/BresenHam-3D-helix.pdf